# Is it possible to restrict the calculation of frequencies in ORCA program?

Tags: computational-chemistry, orca, vibrations

I looked in the orca manual but didn't find anything, but in the case of having a molecule adsorbed in a cluster, is it possible to perform the frequency calculation only on the molecule and not on the entire system?

Many Thanks

Comment: +1, but try to add more context to the question. Anyway, have you tried reading `Partial Hessian Vibrational Analysis` part of the manual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you Andrea Pellegrini, the solution for me was to use the partial hess flag with the number of atoms that I want to exclude of the vibrational calculation, like the exemple below, for the 21 first atoms.

```
%freq
partial_hess {0:20} end
end
```